# How can I learn Qualitative Analysis and all its equations?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Qualitative Analysis, as all may know, has so many equations and each element has its own specific properties - colour, reaction, test etc. How can I learn all this?

Comment: There is not really an easy way out. You'll have to study the compounds, the trends within periods and groups, specific reactions and properties, and comparative reasoning. There is no shortcut. After you have obtained a decent basic knowledge you'll see the links between theories and behaviours of atoms and molecules.

Comment: Well, I'm quite sure I have obtained the _decent basic knowledge_.

Comment: Spend more time with each reaction. Try to identify the reaction types-redox reaction, acid-base, hydrolysis, etc. During this process, you will realize not all the reactions are completely independent. Now, there are a lot of facts that you are supposed to remember, e.g. Try to group the compounds that you find similar. For eg. color of the compounds or specific complexes. Note patterns, e.g. All sulphides that you will encounter in your course will be black except CdS(yellow), MnS(pink), SnS2(yellow),SnS(brown), ZnS(white). Most chromates are yellow and phosphates and sulphates are white.

Answer (score 4):

As *Martin* has pointed out in his comment, there is no way to get around learning, but you might want to look for a system that interconnects the seemingly overwhelming amount of facts.

In German chemistry education, the *Kationentrennungsgang* is a **systematic workflow** to separate and qualitatively detect cations from a complex mixture.

In the course of this workflow,

- **groups of cations** are subsequently precipitated from the mixture and then
- analyzed separately by bringing them into solution again, one by one.

In the simple *Kationentrennungsgang*, the cations are separated into five groups, namely

1. hydrochloric acid group
2. hydrogen sulfide group
3. ammonium sulfide group
4. ammonium carbonate group
5. soluble group

Typically, you start by adding concentrated concentrated hydrochloric acid to your sample. This will precipitate  $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$, $\ce{HgCl2}$, $\ce{PbCl2}$, $\ce{AgCl}$, and $\ce{TlCl}$, if present. Cations of the groups 2-5 will remain in solution.

To repeat the sad news: There is now way around memorizing a lot of facts, but using the *Kationentrennungsgang*, you will learn a lot about periodic trends.